# Change scores/difference scores on a logarithmic scale

Tags: logarithms, transformation, natural-transformations

From a longitudinal cohort-study I have two datapoints per patient on arterial calcification ($x_{new}$ and $x_{old}$). To determine risk factors for calcification-change I want to use a linear regression model. To determine the change I have calculated actual change in mass ($d_{actual}=x_{new} - x_{old}$) and relative change ($d_{relative}= (x_{new} - x_{old}) / x_{old}$ * 100%). Both change measures are important for my analyses.

However, to deal with the high skewness of $x_{new}, x_{old}, d_{actual}$, and $d_{relative}$  I want to transform these variables. I've done this by taking the natural logs of the original variables (as that produced the most normal distribution), first adding +1 to scores as a lot of patients have calcification scores of 0. So: $x_{new, transf}= log (x_{new}+1)$ and  $x_{old, transf}= log(x_{old}+1)$. In these transformed scores, the patients that had no calcification still have a score of 0, as Log(1)=0.

Subsequently, I calculated the relative change score for the transformed variable using the formula above ($d_{relative, transf}$= ($x_{new, transf}$ - $x_{old, transf}$) / $x_{old,transf}$ * 100%), but first adding a random constant (1 in this case) to $x_{new,transf}$ and $x_{old,transf}$.

I've got a few questions about this:

1. For the transformed variables, does adding the constant +1 áfter transformation not alter the relative changes?
2. What would be the difference between the transformed change variables as described above (so first transform, and then calculate change), and if I would have just taken the log of the change scores (so first calculate change and then transform).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The equations you're using are not really well explained here. I'll take a guess, so tell me if this is correct: You have the values $x_{\text{old}}$ and $x_{\text{new}}$ and the quantity you're calculating is
$$
\frac{
\ln(x_{\text{new}}+1)
}{
\ln(x_{\text{old}}+1)
}
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Also, you're saying "how much do I add to the Log transformed variable?" - What is your goal here? Apparently you want to add some constant somewhere, but why is this? Also, why have you taken the logarithm at all, to begin with? Why wouldn't $x_{\text{new}}/x_{\text{old}}$ suffice (excluding the case $x_{\text{old}}=0$)?

Comment: Hi @MattiP., thanks very much for your reply. 
I've edited my question so it is more clear what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarifications. But it's still difficult to answer your question, I would need more information and context. You mentioned that the data is skewed, right? But with respect to what? Can you show a graph of some kind? Also, you mentioned that you want to use linear regression. That sounds to me like you're trying to model how the calcification (or something) changes with respect to something else. What is this something else? Do you have data for another variable that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: I'll try and be as specific as possible. Calcification is measured on a continuous scale (mass) and is right skewed, in the sense that no/little calcification is most prevalent with larger amounts becoming increasingly less prevalent. 
The plan is to regress the calcification change-scores on age, sex, and several dichotomized cardiovascular risk factors (hypertension, hypercholesterolemia, smoking, obesity, chronic-kidney-disease, diabetes) to adjust for confounding.
However, preparing the data led to the questions that I've asked in the main question.